# Sheaf-type property for Derived Categories?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, homological-algebra, sheaf-theory, derived-categories

Suppose $X$ is a finite dimensional complex space (I'm happy to restrict to $X$ being a scheme of finite type over $\mathbb C$ as well). I'm wondering if the following sheaf-like properties hold for objects and morphisms of the derived category of finite complexes of coherent sheaves. Below, the complexes of sheaves we consider are finite complexes of coherent sheaves on $X$, which are (locally on $X$) quasi-isomorphic to a finite complex of locally free sheaves.

(1) Suppose we are given two morphisms $\phi^\bullet,\psi^\bullet:E^\bullet\to F^\bullet$ between two complexes of sheaves on $X$. To check that they define the same morphisms in the derived category, is it enough to check this locally on $X$? For example, if we are able to produce a finite open cover $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ of $X$ such that the maps $\phi^\bullet|_{U_i},\psi^\bullet|_{U_i}$ are homotopic, is it true that $\phi^\bullet,\psi^\bullet$ are globally homotopic or at least define the same morphism in the derived category (possibly with some additional assumptions on $X$)?

(2) Suppose we are given a finite open cover $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ of $X$, and finite complexes of locally free sheaves $E^\bullet_i$ on each $U_i$, with specified quasi-isomorphisms $\phi_{ij}$ on each pairwise intersection $U_i\cap U_j$ satisfying a cocycle-type condition (possibly involving some data of homotopies etc on higher overlaps of the $U_i$'s). Is it then possible to "patch" these together to get a well-defined object in the derived category of $X$? If so, I would be interested in a precise statement of this and a reference for a proof.

(3) In the vein of (2), can locally defined morphisms between finite complexes of locally free sheaves be glued together (if they satisfy appropriate conditions on the overlaps) to give globally well-defined morphisms in the derived category?

Precise statements and proofs/references will be appreciated. I apologize in advance if these are very basic questions.

Comment: (1) No, e.g. a non-split extension of vector bundles $0\to E\to F\to G\to 0$ defines a nonzero map in the derived category $G\to E[1]$ which is zero locally because the sequence is locally split. (2) Yes, but the key is the "higher homotopies". You should definitely read up on higher topoi and the derived infinity-category, which has the higher stack conditions you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Could you give me some reference(s) where I can read a precise statement/proof about patching objects of the derived category over an open cover?

Comment: Also, could someone answer/comment on (3) and suggest references for that as well?